# I am being asked to add functions to my code and need help doing so

Tags: function

I designed code for a GUI grade Calculator but now I am being asked to add 1. create a function that will contain all of your data validation code. The function should return  true  if all data checks have passed or a false if any of the data is invalid. If the data is valid (true returned), add the number to the list box, if it is not valid (false returned), show an error message.2)Add a Sub procedure that will reset the form fields back to their initial state. Call this sub procedure when the clear button is clicked.

2.add a Sub procedure that will reset the form fields back to their initial state. Call this sub procedure when the clear button is clicked.

3. create a function that will count the 90s in the listbox. Pass the listbox in a a parameter and loop the contents to count each of the 90s in the listbox. Return the count of the 90s in the list box to the caller. Use it as input in the re-write eligibility check.

This is my Code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BuGrade_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuGrade.Click
        gradeList.Items.Add(txtgrade.Text)
        txtgrade.Clear()
    End Sub

Private Sub BuAverage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuAverage.Click
    Dim total As Double
    Dim avg As Double
    Dim grade As Double
    Dim gradecount As Integer
    For gradecount = 0 To gradeList.Items.Count - 1
        grade = gradeList.Items(gradecount)
        total += grade
    Next
    avg = total / gradeList.Items.Count
    lblR.Text = "The final total score is " & total & vbCrLf & "The Average score is " & avg

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lblR.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: I am not sure but it is on Visual Basic it is NET Framework

Comment: Doesnt help I didnt get in to the class until late. I really need help with this because I dont full understand :(

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to help you if we don't know what language it's in.

Comment: its C# im pretty positive